# Add django model manager code-completion to Komodo

Tags: python, django, komodo

I have been using ActiveState Komodo for a while and while most of the code-completion is spot on it lacks the code completion from Django's model manager.

I have included the Django directory in my `PYTHONPATH` and get most of the code completion, the notable exception being the models.

Assuming I have a model `users` I would expect the code `users.objects.` to show autocomplete options such as `all()`,`count()`,`filter()` etc. however these are added by the model's manager which does so in a seemingly abnormal way.

I am wondering if I can 'force' Komodo to pick up the models.

The model manager looks to be included from the following code (taken from manager.py)

```
def ensure_default_manager(sender, **kwargs):
"""
Ensures that a Model subclass contains a default manager  and sets the
_default_manager attribute on the class. Also sets up the _base_manager
points to a plain Manager instance (which could be the same as
_default_manager if it's not a subclass of Manager).
"""
cls = sender
if cls._meta.abstract:
    return
if not getattr(cls, '_default_manager', None):
    # Create the default manager, if needed.
    try:
        cls._meta.get_field('objects')
        raise ValueError("Model %s must specify a custom Manager, because it has a field named 'objects'" % cls.__name__)
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        pass
    cls.add_to_class('objects', Manager())
    cls._base_manager = cls.objects
...
```

Specifically the last two lines. Is there any way to tell Komodo that `<model>.objects = Manager()` so the proper code completion is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get this to work seems to be to add the following to the top of models.py:

```
from django.db.models import manager
```

and then under each model add

```
objects = manager.Manager()
```

so that, for example, the following:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

becomes

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = manager.Manager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is how you would (explicitly) set your own model manager, and by explicitly setting the model manager (to the default) Kommodo picks up the code completion perfectly.

Hopefully this will help someone :-)

Comment: If there are any better ways of doing this please let me know (such as doing the above auto-magically)